# responsiveTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added the below code in my aspx page.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.responsivetable.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#grdStudent').responsiveTable({
            staticColumns: 2,
            scrollRight: true,
            scrollHintEnabled: true,
            scrollHintDuration: 2000
        });
    });
</script>
```

but I am getting  "responsiveTable is not a function". Can anyone please help me on this.

N.B. responsiveTable  reference http://declanbright.awardspace.info/jquery-plugin-responsive-table

Comment: Does it load the script successfully?

Comment: Yes, I have saved the jquery file in local and reference that file in my code.

Answer (score 0):

> The Responsive Table jQuery Plugin is a lightweight plugin which adds
>   responsive behaviour to a HTML table.

Make sure that you are calling jquery before responsiveTable.js file.

In below example `staticColumns:2` it means there will be two column will display as static.

Please check an example :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#grdStudent').responsiveTable({
            staticColumns: 2,
            scrollRight: true,
            scrollHintEnabled: true,
            scrollHintDuration: 2000
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://declanbright.awardspace.info/downloads/jquery.responsivetable.min.js"></script>


<table class="demo-table" id="grdStudent">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Column B</th>
            <th>Column C</th>
            <th>Column D</th>
            <th>Column E</th>
            <th style="width:3em;"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell B1</td>
            <td>Cell C1</td>
            <td>Cell D1</td>
            <td>Cell E1</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Button"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell B2</td>
            <td>Cell C2</td>
            <td>Cell D2</td>
            <td>Cell E2</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Button"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell B3</td>
            <td>Cell C3</td>
            <td>Cell D3</td>
            <td>Cell E3</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Button"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can also visit : [CodePen example here](https://codepen.io/saAction/full/OoGPRB)